# multiple phrases connected with comma

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases, commas

> I aspire to help organizations achieve their goals by solving the
>   issues in the areas of customer focus, employee engagement, adapting
>   for change, managing in complex environment and work-life balance

Question :- Are last 3 points **"adapting for change"**, **"managing in complex environment"** and **"work-life balance"** fitting well with rest of the sentence?

Comment: It's one of those sentences  where readers are likely to forget the beginning by the time they reach the end. When you have a series of aims such as these, the use of bullet points is often the best way to lay them out.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing verb phrases and noun phrases, which is a problem with parallelism.

Really, each item should be of one form or the other.

For instance:

> I aspire to help organizations achieve their goals by *solving* [] issues in the [area] of customer focus, ***engaging*** employees, *adapting* for change, *managing* [complex environments], and ***balancing*** work [and] life.

I made some additional tweaks in the areas with square brackets, but the main point is that all of the items now start with an *-ing*-formed verb.

Now it doesn't have any problems with grammar.

---

As some comments have said, however, you might want to do something to make it easier to parse.

You could use a vertical list:

> I aspire to help organizations achieve their goals by
>
> - solving issues in the area of customer focus,
> - engaging employees,
> - adapting for change,
> - managing complex environments, and
> - balancing work life.

Or, you could keep everything horizontal but help the items stand out like this:

> I aspire to help organizations achieve their goals by (1) solving issues in the area of customer focus, (2) engaging employees, (3) adapting for change, (4) managing complex environments, and (5) balancing work and life.